# Xml different screens issue in Android

Tags: android, xml, size

[image: This is the snapshot of Htc Desire S screen...]

[image: And this is the snapshot of Samsumg galaxy s3 screen...]

Hello i am facing a problem with different android mobile phones... the buttons not fill whole screen. in htc it is perfect but in galaxy s3 the buttons not fill the whole screen. this is some of the portion my Xml of main activity... please let me 
know what to do???  thanx

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/anaheim"
            android:height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width"
            android:width="@dimen/abc_search_view_preferred_width" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/boston"
            android:height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width"
            android:width="@dimen/abc_search_view_preferred_width" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Really? Do you have a empty scrollview?

Comment: you should create different XML files for different screen sizes, or screens DPI, or simply add "match_parent" for button width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons need to be with

```
width="match_parent"
```

So

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button31"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/anaheim"
        android:height="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width"
        android:width="@dimen/abc_search_view_preferred_width" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its not empty it contain all buttons

Comment: its just miss-printing

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you should use

**match_parent**

in place of

**wrap_content**

for **button width**, and also put your images into **drawable** folder, instead of *drawable-hdpi* ***[create drawable folder in res, if not exist]***

**Note:-** In your case you ***don't need to create different - different images for multiple screen size(s)***, because **drawable folder** will help you out from this issue, will automatically pick fit to device...using **drawable**